# Meteor logout on stale session logout

Tags: session, meteor

I am new to meteor.js and I am sorry if my question is not appropriate according to the community standards.

Well, I am trying to create a simple application on it and came across a problem of timing out after the user inactivity.

I am using "stale session meteor package" to automatically timeout the user after some specified time of inactivity. It logs off the user but doesn't unset the "Meteor.user()" by which I could know in meteor that the user has been logged out and call the route for the "Login" page to re-login.

Example, the stale session logs off the user after 30 seconds of inactivity, then I checked the returned value of "Meteor.user()", It should have returned undefined if the stale-session is timed out, instead, it is running the complete user object with id and other details.

I simply want to forcefully logout the user when the stale session times out and show the login screen.

I have been searching on internet for two days but couldn't find any solution on how to do this. Finally, posted the question.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't properly installed/used the stale session package. How do you know that the user has been logged off? If `Meteor.user()` still has a value then it would appear they are still logged in. Also, check `Meteor.userId()` instead of `Meteor.user()` for a user being logged in. The former can exist before the latter due to the time required to publish the complete user object over the network, especially if the user object is large.

Comment: Well, By "user log off" I meant the stale session way of logging out not the meteor way. The stale session sets/updates the users table field of loginToken to empty and the project becomes useless.
Yeah i checked Meteor.userId() too but no success

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution and it is working so posting it here if somebody need.

I dug into the stale package code, and in its client.js I replaced the code with this

```
Meteor.setInterval(function() {
if (Meteor.userId()) {

    if(activityDetected){
        Meteor.call('heartbeat');
        activityDetected = false;
    } else {
        //This is the wanted behavior
        Meteor.logout();
    }
}

}, heartbeatInterval);
```

If no activity is detected in terms of jquery events, I simply call logout and dont need to worry about Meteor.user() or Meteor.userId() etc. It simply logs out and goes to the Login Screen route which I implemented.